# How to parse the following xml: A case of recursion

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, gdataxml

I have the following xml. I am trying to parse this using gdataxml parser.  I am able to parse the first part of the xml, `<myBean>` to `</myBean>`, but from the second part, from `<trackBean>`, it s becoming harder as the `trackBean` is recursing inside. I am finding it hard to develop a logic for that. I am stuck here for the 2nd day.

```
 <return>
   <myTrackBean>
    <myBean>
                <myStatus>false</myStatus>
                <hisStatus>false</hisStatus>
                 <secondVcardBean>
                     <contactId>108</contactId>                         
                     <myNumber>KXUOYHGCIO</myNumber>
                     <userId>56</userId>
                     <version>1</version>                         
                </secondVcardBean>
                <myNumber>KXUOYHGCIO</myNumber>
            </myBean>
            <trackBean>
               <myBean>
                  <myStatus>false</myStatus>
                  <hisStatus>false</hisStatus>
                  <secondVcardBean>
                     <contactId>105</contactId>
                     <myNumber>5D1X7XP6CW</myNumber>
                     <userId>54</userId>
                     <version>1</version>
                 </secondVcardBean>
                 <myNumber>5D1X7XP6CW</myNumber>
             </myBean>
             <trackBean>
                <myBean>
                     <myStatus>false</myStatus>
                     <hisStatus>false</hisStatus>
                     <secondVcardBean>
                         <contactId>103</contactId>
                         <myNumber>0C3RM5UKBB</myNumber>
                         <userId>53</userId>
                         <version>8</version>
                     </secondVcardBean>
                    <myNumber>0C3RM5UKBB</myNumber>
                </myBean>
          </trackBean>
      </trackBean>
  </myTrackBean>
</return>
```

The following is the code I have used for parsing the first part, from the first `<myBean>` to <`myBean>`. How can I check whether a `<trackBean>` exists inside its parent `<trackBean>`

```
NSArray * array = [node nodesForXPath:@"//return/myTrackBean" error:nil];

            int noOfmyTrackBean = [array count];

            for(int i = 1; i<= noOfmyTrackBean; i++){


                NSString *tempXmlData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//return/myTrackBean/myBean"];

                NSString *myStatus = [node nodeStringForXPath:[tempXmlData stringByAppendingString:@"/myStatus"]];

                NSString *hisStatus = [node nodeStringForXPath:[tempXmlData stringByAppendingString:@"/hisStatus"]];

                NSString *contactId = [node nodeStringForXPath:[tempXmlData stringByAppendingString:@"/secondVcardBean/contactId"]];

                NSString *myNumber = [node nodeStringForXPath:[tempXmlData stringByAppendingString:@"/secondVcardBean/myNumber"]];
```

I understand that the difficulty is in getting the `<trackBean>` child node inside `<trackBean>`

Comment: Answer is here go http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1000963

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for GDataXml Parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont need to worry a lot about recursion, as gdataxml seems to handle that part internally. You can just parse it normally as the parser object takes the count of the nodes  that repeats inside itself. I dont know if its exactly what to you need, but it will definitely help you.

```
NSArray * array = [node nodesForXPath:@"//return/myTrackBean" error:nil];
            NSLog(@"count  :%d",[array count]);
            NSLog(@"Node  :%@",node);

            int noOfPrimaryNodes = [array count];

            for(int i = 1; i<= noOfPrimaryNodes; i++){

                //For use from the second node
                NSString *myxmlData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//return/myTrackBean/trackBean"];
                NSLog(@"myxmlData  :%@",myxmlData);


                NSArray *array = [node nodesForXPath:@"//return/myTrackBean/trackBean" error:nil];

                NSLog(@"Array count %d", [array count]);
                if([array count]>0){
                GDataXMLElement *myNode = [[node nodesForXPath:@"//return/myTrackBean/trackBean" error:&error]objectAtIndex:0];
                 NSLog(@"myNode  :%@",myNode);



                NSString *changingNode = @"//trackBean";


                for(int j = 0; j < [array count]; j++){

                    NSString *myStatus = [node nodeStringForXPath:[changingNode stringByAppendingString:@"/myBean/myStatus"]];
                    NSString * hisStatus = [node nodeStringForXPath:[changingNode stringByAppendingString:@"/myBean/hisStatus"]];
                    NSString *contactId = [node nodeStringForXPath:[changingNode stringByAppendingString:@"/myBean/secondVcardBean/contactId"]];
                    NSString *myNumber = [node nodeStringForXPath:[changingNode stringByAppendingString:@"/myBean/secondVcardBean/myNumber"]];
                    NSString *versionNumber = [node nodeStringForXPath:[changingNode stringByAppendingString:@"/myBean/secondVcardBean/versionNumber"]];
         }
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

[How To Read and Write XML Documents with GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)